# Getting initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, tvos

I know this may not be the right place to ask this particular question, but I've tried contacting the author of the GitHub repository below, and there has been no response so far.

So, I've found [this](https://github.com/Ingemark/TVMultiPicker) particularly useful library on GitHub, which essentially allows for the creation of one or more 'pickers' on tvOS. It comes with a handy pre-made date picker, which uses a `MultiPickerConfiguration` class to handle UI configuration amongst other properties.

However, after pulling in the library via Cocoapods, I seem unable to instantiate my own `MultiPickerConfiguration` object. I've tried creating a new initializer via an `extension`, but Xcode complains with the following message:

```
initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
```

I'm kinda stumped at this point, and I would really like not to have to pull in the entire `.xcproj` into my `.xcworkspace`.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct needs a public init method. Either the author needs to add one or you could ad one and submit it as a pull request.

> The default memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered
>   private if any of the structure’s stored properties are private.
>   Likewise, if any of the structure’s stored properties are file
>   private, the initializer is file private. Otherwise, the initializer
>   has an access level of internal.
>
> As with the default initializer above, if you want a public structure
>   type to be initializable with a memberwise initializer when used in
>   another module, you must provide a public memberwise initializer
>   yourself as part of the type’s definition.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID21

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. However, seeing that the author has been MIA for quite some time, is there any way for me to add the `init` via an extension, or some way that doesn't involve touching the base code of the library?

Comment: Nope. Since all the properties are internal, you don't have access to them to create an init method. You could fork the repo and make the changes yourself.

Comment: That's the answer I've been dreading, but probably the only one that exists. :) Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Someone else seems to have the same problem and posted this [issue](https://github.com/Ingemark/TVMultiPicker/issues/3).

Seeing that the last commit is February 2018, I doubt anyone is going to fix it any time soon. You can submit a pull request and wait for someone to merge it.

In the mean time, you can add a public initializer by editing the code. Find the code for the pod in the left panel: `Pods > Pods > TVMultiPicker > MultiPickerConfiguration.swift`. Start typing and a dialog box will show up and ask you whether you want to unlock the file. Click "Unlock" and write your initialiser.

Comment: Ah, actually, that was me who posted that issue, lol. And yes, I am aware that I can modify the base code of the downloaded pod, but I as a general rule of thumb, I try not to do so. Thanks for your tip though! :)